# What is the behavior of toolTip.AutoPopDelay=0

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have set toolTip.AutoPopDelay=1, and the tooltip is shown for just 1 milli sec and hided.

and when I have set toolTip.AutoPopDelay = 0, but still the tooltip is showing for some time like 5 secs.

Could anyone please let me know, is there any behavior of setting any default value when AutoPopDelay is set to O?

Regards,

Comment: Why would you want to set `AutoPopDelay` to zero in the first place? Also, be sure to look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.autopopdelay(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Due [ToolTip.AutoPopDelay MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.autopopdelay(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The period of time, in milliseconds, that the ToolTip remains visible when the pointer is stationary on a control.The default value is 5000.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such behavior at play, why you are seeing it 5 seconds is not expected behavior.

I just made a text project with:

```
myToolTip.SetToolTip( myButton, "SomeText" );
myToolTip.AutoPopDelay = 0;
```

And I only saw the tooltip flash when I put my mouse on it.